# different mysql select statement but sleep long time

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I used flask+SQLAlchemy, and in teardown_appcontext I have called db.session.remove().But there are different select statement which slept long time until wait_timeout closed it, and connection pool can not recycle it with error 'sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 1 overflow 0 reached, connection timed out'(For test I set pool_size 1).This problem is not definite, even to same sql.

```
Sql like:

select * from some_table where type = 1 and online = 1;
I use sqlalchemy orm, so the code like SomeTable.query.filter(...).first()
```

```
mysql config:

innodb
REPEATABLE-READ
wait_timeout=7200
max_connection=500
```

```
I have tried:

1. I make a breakpoint in teardown_appcontext, and the dirty, deleted, new of db.session is null, which means I don't update anything.
2. I don't think the cause is deadlock.Sometime just one select statement is sleep.Maybe other lock?
```

```
More information:

mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_TRX\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 328279913521420
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2020-07-17 01:06:34
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 0
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 2230
                 trx_query: NULL
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 0
         trx_tables_locked: 0
          trx_lock_structs: 0
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 1136
           trx_rows_locked: 0
         trx_rows_modified: 0
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 0
          trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0


mysql> show engine innodb status;
| InnoDB |      |
=====================================
2020-07-17 11:58:02 0x2af011ecd700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 43 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 6510 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 3181472 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 3187982
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 7090
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 6906
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 13702, OS waits 6750
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 9089, OS waits 86
RW-sx spins 425, rounds 8010, OS waits 102
Spin rounds per wait: 13702.00 RW-shared, 9089.00 RW-excl, 18.85 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 284153
Purge done for trx's n:o < 284127 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 20
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 328679933520608, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328679933519696, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 10 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 11 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 12 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 13 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 14 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 15 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 16 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 17 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 18 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 19 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 20 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 21 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 22 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 23 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 24 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 25 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 26 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 27 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 28 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 29 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 30 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 31 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 32 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 33 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 34 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 35 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 36 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 37 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 38 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 39 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 40 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 41 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 42 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 43 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 44 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 45 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 46 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 47 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 48 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 49 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 50 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 51 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 52 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 53 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 54 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 55 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 56 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 57 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 58 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 59 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 60 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 61 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 62 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 63 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 64 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 65 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 66 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 67 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 68 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 69 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 70 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 71 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 72 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 73 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 74 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 75 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 76 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 77 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 78 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 79 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 80 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 81 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
1375 OS file reads, 71241 OS file writes, 50288 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.07 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 6 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1182691, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 120244771
Log flushed up to   120244771
Pages flushed up to 120244771
Last checkpoint at  120244762
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
22110 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 4397727744
Dictionary memory allocated 1539743
Buffer pool size   262112
Free buffers       259117
Database pages     2983
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1149, created 1844, written 35803
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2983, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[24]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32474
Database pages     288
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 124, created 164, written 6054
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 288, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32361
Database pages     402
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 111, created 291, written 3812
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 402, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32422
Database pages     340
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 87, created 253, written 640
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 340, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32367
Database pages     396
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 204, created 192, written 7007
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 396, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32353
Database pages     409
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 203, created 206, written 3725
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 409, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32319
Database pages     444
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 161, created 283, written 2956
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 444, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32358
Database pages     404
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 155, created 259, written 7777
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 404, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   32764
Free buffers       32463
Database pages     300
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 104, created 196, written 3832
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 300, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[3]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=2960, Main thread ID=47210533119744, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 40379, updated 4331, deleted 1131, read 2800340
0.12 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.12 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Have you checked uf your db server is not having hardware issues (storage problems)?

Comment: I dumped the db and tested it in local environment, storage was available.I don't kown what it is waiting.

Comment: I mean corrupted storage/journal whatever, not disk full. But if you gitva db dump - tried importing to different machine to see the same query behavior? Also, peek syslog

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Finally I found the key.In our projcet, it used ThreadPoolExecutor to call third party service and the function wrapped by app_context and req_context like `ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top` and `with ctx:`.When it waited for return `future.result()`, the call timed out and raised a exception, which caused connection pool leak.Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post this as answer and then mark it accepted once SO will let you do so, to mark your problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used ThreadPoolExecutor to call third party service and the function wrapped by app_context and req_context like ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top and with ctx:.When it waited for return future.result(), the call timed out and raised a exception, which caused connection pool leak.